Global exception handler on Blazor Web Assembly
I'm looking to set up global exception handler that will pop up a toast message on error.
I don't want to use ErrorBoundary as I want to stay on current view.
Is there any similar approach to having a global exception handler middleware as you would on a .net core api?
I know it's not an API, but just wondering there is something similar on blazor wasm.
Thanks!
